# pgAdmin on OpenShift using RedHat base image

Tags: docker, openshift, redhat, pgadmin

I am trying to create an image for OpenShift v4 using RedHat universal base image(registry.access.redhat.com/ubi8/ubi). Unfortunately this image comes with some limitations at least for me, i.e. missing wget and on top I have corporate proxy messing up with the SSL certificates so I am creating builds from dockerfile and running them directly in OpenShift.

So far my Dockerfile looks like:

```
FROM registry.access.redhat.com/ubi8/ubi

RUN \
    dnf install -y https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/reporpms/EL-8-aarch64/pgdg-redhat-repo-latest.noarch.rpm && \
    dnf install -y postgresql13-server

CMD [ "systemctl start postgresql-13" ]
```

This ends-up with "Error: GPG check FAILED". I need some help how to create the proper Dockerfile using an image from RedHat and the rpm package for Docker. Any other ideas are pretty welcome.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

1. "Error: GPG check FAILED" is telling you that your system is not trusting that repo. You need to import it's key as  `rpm --import https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/RPM-GPG-KEY-PGDG-AARCH64` or whichever key is right for your version
2. You don't want to start a postgres server with a systemd, that's actually against the container philosophy of running a single process inside container. Also, you can't have a proper pid 1 inside openshift without messing with SCCs, since the main idea of openshift restrictions is to run unprivileged containers, so getting systemd might be impossible in your environment.
3. Look at the existing postgres dockerfiles out there to gain inspiration, i.e. very popular [bitnami postgres image](https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-postgresql/blob/master/13/debian-10/Dockerfile). Notice that there is entrypoint.sh, which checks if database is already initialized, and creates it if it's not. Then in actually launces as `postgres "-D" "$POSTGRESQL_DATA_DIR" "--config-file=$POSTGRESQL_CONF_FILE" "--external_pid_file=$POSTGRESQL_PID_FILE" "--hba_file=$POSTGRESQL_PGHBA_FILE"`
4. Unless you really need a postgres 13 built upon rhel 8 UBI, i suggest you to look at official redhat docker images, here is the link if you want to build them yourself - https://github.com/sclorg/postgresql-container . As you can see - building a proper postgresql is quite a task, and without working all the quirks and knowing everything beforehand - you may end up with improperly configured or corrupted database.
5. You may also have postgres helm charts, templates or even operators configured in you cluster, and deploying a database can be as easy as couple of clicks.

TL,DR: Do not reinvent the wheel and do not create custom database images unless you have to. And if you have to - draw inspiration from existing Dockerfiles from reputable vendors.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the given advise! Actually I already have a  Postgres from OpenShift/RedHat. I am trying to run a management tool for the DB because on PROD environment I don't have terminal in OpenShift(company policy) and I cannot use the Postres' CLI. I am trying to run pgAdmin but there is no image in RedHat that I can leverage. I saw they have an rpm package for RHEL and that's why I am trying with it. My plan B is to use s2i and build Adminer since it is PHP based.

Comment: Sorry, totally misread pgadmin part, even when it was in question description :) I'l try to improve that answer later, but the first and second point still stands - you have to import keys and you don't actually need systemd. You may look at https://github.com/thaJeztah/pgadmin4-docker/blob/master/Dockerfile meanwhile - it seems that having postgresql binaries and python with some packages is enough, should be not that hard to convert this Dockerfile to RPM-based distro